# How can I decrypt an encrypted MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 value in C#, that was encrypted by mcrypt in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, cryptography, aes

I am trying to read a Base64-Encoded value from a Database table managed on the Linux side. In that 
table there is a column called first_name. On the Linux side I can decrypt this easily by using the following command in PHP:

```
$data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "patient_fn_salt",
                       base64_decode("H6XmkH+VWvdD88THCliKJjLisGZIBk3CTNvyQMLnhpo="),
                       MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

However I try as much as I can to duplicate this logic on the C# side and all I get is gibberish.

My C# code is below, i hope you have some suggestions because I ran out of ideas :(

```
byte [] cipherText =
         Convert.FromBase64String("H6XmkH+VWvdD88THCliKJjLisGZIBk3CTNvyQMLnhpo=");
byte [] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("patient_fn_salt");
Array.Resize(ref key, 32);
byte [] iv = new byte[32];

string fname = Utilities.Decrypt(cipherText, key, iv);


public static string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
  {
   // Check arguments.
   if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
   if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
   if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

   // TDeclare the streams used
   // to decrypt to an in memory
   // array of bytes.
   MemoryStream msDecrypt = null;
   CryptoStream csDecrypt = null;
   StreamReader srDecrypt = null;

   // Declare the AesManaged object
   // used to decrypt the data.
   RijndaelManaged rj = new RijndaelManaged();

   // Declare the string used to hold
   // the decrypted text.
   string plaintext = null;

   try
   {
    // Create an AesManaged object
    // with the specified key and IV.

    rj.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    rj.BlockSize = 256;
    rj.KeySize = 256;
    rj.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    rj.Key = Key;
    rj.GenerateIV();
    //rj.IV = IV;


    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = rj.CreateDecryptor(rj.Key, rj.IV);

    // Create the streams used for decryption.
    msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText);
    csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt);

    // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
    // and place them in a string.
    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
   }
   finally
   {
    // Clean things up.

    // Close the streams.
    if (srDecrypt != null)
     srDecrypt.Close();
    if (csDecrypt != null)
     csDecrypt.Close();
    if (msDecrypt != null)
     msDecrypt.Close();

    // Clear the AesManaged object.
    if (rj != null)
     rj.Clear();
   }
   return plaintext;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe this can help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net

Comment: Just one note: The `IV` parameter is not used in your method ... and ECB mode does not have initialization vectors. (But I don't think this does relate to your problem.)

Answer (score 6):

Post is old, but this might help somebody in a future. This function encrypt exactly like mcrypt_encrypt with parameters MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 and MCRYPT_MODE_ECB

```
    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] key)
    {
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        byte[] encrypted;
        using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.BlockSize = 256;
            rijAlg.Key = key;
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            rijAlg.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
```

And here is function to decrypt it

```
     static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key)
     {
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        string plaintext;
        using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.BlockSize = 256;
            rijAlg.Key = key;
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            rijAlg.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
            using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return plaintext;
    }
```

Comment: I hope this will not be useful to anybody, since if it is, it means they're using quite questionable crypto.

Answer (score 5):

As  Paŭlo says, ECB mode does not use an IV.  If C# insists on one then use all zero bytes.

The key "patient_fn_salt" is 15 characters, 120 bits.  Your decryption function is expecting 256 bits of key.  You need to be **very** sure that the extra bits are identical in both systems and are being added in the same place in both systems.  Even a single bit wrong will result in garbage decryption.  Read the PHP documentation very carefully to determine exactly how "patient_fn_salt" is expanded to a 256 bit key.  In particular check if the actual key is `SHA256("patient_fn_salt")`.

As an aside, ECB mode is insecure.  Use either CTR mode or CBC mode in preference.  CTR mode does not require padding so will probably mean less cyphertext to store.

ETA: on another read through I notice that the C# side is padding with zeros.  What padding is the PHP side using?  Zero padding is not a good idea, as it cannot recognise a faulty decryption.  PKCS7 padding has a much better chance of recognising a faulty output.  Best to explicitly specify the padding on both ends rather than rely on defaults.

Comment: The [documentation says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php): *If it's smaller than the required keysize, it is padded with '\0'.* ... and Array.Resize looks as if it does the same. But maybe explicit padding is more safe.

Comment: It would be useful to directly check the contents of the two byte arrays if possible.  Failing that, explicit padding would certainly be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem when comunicating with a legacy system. I had to come up with my own solution as Rijndael with a Blocksize of 256 seems to be not supported by dotnet core.

Here is my solution using the bouncy castle library:

```
    public static byte[] Rijandael256Decrypt(byte[] inputBytes, byte[] keyBytes)
    {
        // set up
        IBufferedCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256), new ZeroBytePadding());
        KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(keyBytes);
        cipher.Init(false, keyParam);
        int sizeAtLeastRequired = cipher.GetOutputSize(inputBytes.Length);
        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[sizeAtLeastRequired];

        // decrypt            
        int length = cipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, outputBytes, 0);
        length += cipher.DoFinal(outputBytes, length);

        // resize output
        Array.Resize(ref outputBytes, length);
        return outputBytes;
    }
```