# What is the corresponding Powershell module for the PHP encryption library using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256?

Tags: php, powershell, encryption, mcrypt, rijndael

PHP code:

`mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $to_encrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);`

I need the corresponding powershell code which can produce the same result.

I have already tried ConvertTo-SecureString/ ConvertFrom-SecureString.

Powershell Code (Not producing correct encryption):

```
$api_code = "214e3854a1ec5433ae986d1e5d40c436"
$params = @{"controller" = $controller; "action"= $action;  "all"= $TRUE; }
[Byte[]] $key = $api_code[0..$api_code.length]
$param_object = $params | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$param_aes = $param_object | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $key
```

The encrypted string is coming out different. Is there a parameter that I am missing? Or Is there another module?

Comment: SecureString has nothing in common with Rijndael / AES. It's a windows thing that uses DPAPI. You should instead look at using the .NET AesManaged class.

Comment: I've got no knowledge of PowerShell whatsoever, but judging by the `$param_aes` variable that you're using, you seem to be assuming that you need AES encryption ... However (and this is a common mistake), MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is NOT AES, only MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 is.

Comment: @Narf So... the `256` in `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` refers to block size, not key length?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, precisely. :) If you need AES-256, just use a 256-bit key with Rijndael-128.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys! Very helpful. I will try working with AesManaged class. If anyone has a good resource for implementing MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 using AesManaged, please post it here. Actually I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14258619/2970271

Comment: Actually the above link does the same encryption as ConvertTo-SecureString/ ConvertFrom-SecureString. Any help on this?

Comment: @kira_111 adapted a PowerShell equivalent from the `RijndaelManaged` documentation on MSDN, posted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `SecureString`s have nothing to do with the Rijndael specification, and `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is *not* the same as AES256 (which refer Rijndael-128 with a 256-bit key)

So, to solve your problem, we just need a function to encrypt a plaintext in ECB cipher mode using Rijndael with a block size of 256.

For this, the obvious choice is the [`RijndaelManaged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Fortunately, the MSDN documentation provides a basic but fully functional example of how to use the `RijndaelManaged` class and a [`CryptoStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(v=vs.110).aspx) to encrypt and decrypt strings - all we need to do is rewrite it in PowerShell and change the block size and cipher mode:

```psh
function Encrypt-Rijndael256ECB {
    param(
        [byte[]]$Key,
        [string]$Plaintext
    )

    $RijndaelProvider = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged

    # Set block size to 256 to imitate MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256
    $RijndaelProvider.BlockSize = 256
    # Make sure we use ECB mode, or the generated IV will fuck up the first block upon decryption
    $RijndaelProvider.Mode      = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::ECB
    $RijndaelProvider.Key       = $key

    # This object will take care of the actual cryptographic transformation
    $Encryptor = $RijndaelProvider.CreateEncryptor()

    # Set up a memorystream that we can write encrypted data back to
    $EncMemoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    $EncCryptoStream = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream -ArgumentList $EncMemoryStream,$Encryptor,"Write"
    $EncStreamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $EncCryptoStream

    # When we write data back to the CryptoStream, it'll get encrypted and written back to the MemoryStream
    $EncStreamWriter.Write($Plaintext)

    # Close the writer
    $EncStreamWriter.Close()
    # Close the CryptoStream (pads and flushes any data still left in the buffer)
    $EncCryptoStream.Close()
    $EncMemoryStream.Close()

    # Read the encrypted message from the memory stream
    $Cipher     = $EncMemoryStream.ToArray() -as [byte[]]
    $CipherText = [convert]::ToBase64String($Cipher)

    # return base64 encoded encrypted string
    return $CipherText
}
```

The decryption process is almost the same, although this time we'll need to reverse it and read the cipher text back through the CryptoStream from the MemoryStream:

```psh
function Decrypt-Rijndael256ECB {
    param(
        [byte[]]$Key,
        [string]$CipherText
    )

    $RijndaelProvider = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged

    $RijndaelProvider.BlockSize = 256
    $RijndaelProvider.Mode      = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::ECB
    $RijndaelProvider.Key       = $key

    $Decryptor = $RijndaelProvider.CreateDecryptor()

    # Reverse process: Base64Decode first, then populate memory stream with ciphertext and lastly read decrypted data through cryptostream
    $Cipher = [convert]::FromBase64String($CipherText) -as [byte[]]

    $DecMemoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream -ArgumentList @(,$Cipher)
    $DecCryptoStream = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream -ArgumentList $DecMemoryStream,$Decryptor,$([System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode]::Read)
    $DecStreamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $DecCryptoStream

    $NewPlainText = $DecStreamWriter.ReadToEnd()

    $DecStreamWriter.Close()
    $DecCryptoStream.Close()
    $DecMemoryStream.Close()

    return $NewPlainText
}
```

[image: Rijndael256 in action]

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate your effort! This absolutely works.